# Windows Phone 8 App error "No XAML Was Found at the location..."

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I just converted a Win Phone 7.1 app to OS 8.0 and am receiving an error immediately upon launching that it can't find XAML for my start up page. I've tried creating a new page and setting it as the start up and receive the same error. I created a new project and it worked just fine with OS 8 so there must be some issue with this project's conversion.

I thought maybe there could be more to it, maybe an OS7.1 dependency causing an issue. I did have the Ad SDK for 7.1 referenced during conversion. Removing it doesn't change anything.

Any ideas?

Error from RootFrame_NavigationFailed in App.xaml.cs

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: No XAML was found at the location '/Page1.xaml'. at System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.EndLoad(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.ContentLoader_BeginLoad_Callback(IAsyncResult result)}
```

Comment: Have you looked in the WMAppManifest.xml file under Properties? That could be the source of the error.

Comment: Yeah, I've been all over it. Strangely when I open it in designer the capabilities are all false, but they're set in the XML...

Answer (score 0):

Select the page xaml , and in the properties window (ctrl+w,p) check that the build action is set to page , the compiler might not be converting it.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a one line fix; In the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file, you have to change the line:

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]
```

To

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en")]
```

One line fix!. Pity the error message is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there were hidden errors on some xaml in my solution.
Try open **ALL** your xaml by Visual Studio Designer and verify that the preview  is rendered correctly without error. If you find some errors fix-it, close Visual Studio, rebuilt solution and relaunch your App.